# angular multidimensional array live update

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, intervals

I have an endpoint that has 5 users in a obj with 5 arrays. every 5 data changes for a few properties. I want to get the dynamic property, and push it to an array for each user. How can i do this? I need each user to have their own dynamic array.

```
watchMe = [{user: 1 hr: 10},  {user: 2 hr: 20}, {user: 3 hr: 30}];

    updateMe=[];

    function getLive(){
    angular.forEach(watchMe, function(value, key){

     updateMe.push(value.hr);
    console.log (updateMe)
        })
    };
    $interval(getLive, 5000);
```

Comment: can you post some code or snippet with what you have?

Comment: I have a provided an example

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic property"? Why is the property dynamic? Also which property is it?

Comment: Meaning the backend changes the hr property every 5 secs. I want  to push these changes to the updateMe array and has this done for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a utility library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) could provide you with what you're after.

Namely: whenever the interval hits you can use `_.filter` to get you the objects containing the dynamically added property - or just `_.map()` through them and pull the property (if it exists).

*Disclaimer: I would have preferred to add this feedback as a comment but I do not have the rep yet*